# Discord js addedRole executor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically this code, if user gave a role or lost a role log this condition

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let channel = oldMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "member-log");
    let addedRoles = newMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !oldMember.roles.cache.has(role.id));
    let removedRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !newMember.roles.cache.has(role.id));
    
    if (removedRoles.size > 0) {
        const removeRoleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FF0000')
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.user.tag}` , oldMember.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@!${oldMember.id}> kişisinden <@&${removedRoles.map(r => r.id)}> rolü alındı.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Kullanıcı ID : ${oldMember.id}`)
            channel.send(removeRoleEmbed)
    } 
    
    if (addedRoles.size > 0) {
        const addRoleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#80FF00')
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.user.tag}` , oldMember.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@!${oldMember.id}> kişisine <@&${addedRoles.map(r => r.id)}> rolü verildi.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Kullanıcı ID : ${oldMember.id}`)
            channel.send(addRoleEmbed) 
    }
});
```

I have this code and i want who give role a user

Note: Sorry for my english and thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

For that, I believe you need to look at the Audit logs. Now, in Djs v12, you can check audit logs easily. You're looking for the MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE action. [Here are the list of all possible actions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction).
Here's from the Guide on how to listen to Audit Logs:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html

(Assuming async function)

```js
const log = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE' }).then(logs => logs.entries.first());

// This should log the id of the person who gave out that role.
console.log(log.executor.id);
```

That's it.

Comment: @Emir Does your bot have the permission to view audit logs?